# Previous version of Z3 for linux

Tags: z3

Does anyone know how we can get previous versions of z3 for linux 64? I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and it does not include GLIBGXX 3.4.14 which is required by z3 3.2 (the version I currently have). So I was wondering if I could get access to a previous version.

Also if anyone knows how can I overcome this problem (maybe a way to get GLIBCXX 3.4.14) on Ubuntu 10.04 I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.askubuntu.com

Comment: need to update, releases are now under https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old versions are still available on the Z3 website. However, we do not provide links to them. You can download them from

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/

Here is the complete list:

```
z3-2.0.1.tar.gz
z3-2.10.tar.gz
z3-2.11.tar.gz
z3-2.12.tar.gz
z3-2.13.tar.gz
z3-2.15.tar.gz
z3-2.17.tar.gz
z3-2.18-x64.tar.gz
z3-2.18.1.tar.gz
z3-2.18.tar.gz
z3-2.19.1.tar.gz
z3-2.19.tar.gz
z3-2.2.tar.gz
z3-2.3.1.tar.gz
z3-2.3.tar.gz
z3-2.4.1.tar.gz
z3-2.4.tar.gz
z3-2.5.tar.gz
z3-2.6.tar.gz
z3-2.7.tar.gz
z3-2.8.tar.gz
z3-3.0-x64.tar.gz
z3-3.0.tar.gz
z3-3.1.tar.gz
z3-3.2.beta.tar.gz
z3-3.2.tar.gz
z3-4.0.tar.gz
z3-osx-3.2.1.tar.gz
z3-osx-3.2.tar.gz
z3-osx-4.0-preview.tar.gz
z3-osx-4.0.tar.gz
z3-osx32-4.0.tar.gz
z3-x64-2.15.tar.gz
z3-x64-2.18.tar.gz
z3-x64-2.19.tar.gz
z3-x64-3.0.tar.gz
z3-x64-3.1.tar.gz
z3-x64-3.2.beta.tar.gz
z3-x64-3.2.tar.gz
z3-x64-4.0.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo is right, but you can't find the download link in that page. 
You must use the list of programs and use something like:

[http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/**z3-3.2.tar.gz**](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3-3.2.tar.gz)
. You can change the filename in bold by one in the list provided by Leonardo.