# How to install iZ3?

Tags: z3

I'm trying to use iZ3 to generate the interpolants. However, there is no iZ3 binary after installing Z3, and can't find any information about how to install it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iZ3 is not available in the latest version. The Z3 4.1 is the last version that includes iZ3.
This version can be found here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/older_z3.html.
Keep in mind that iZ3 depends on software components that are not owned by Microsoft, and could not be released with the rest of the source code at http://z3.codeplex.com.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm working on Linux, so I can't use the msi file. I tried the oldest version, Z3 4.1.1 , and there is no iZ3 in there. How could I use iZ3 with Linux?

Comment: Here is the link for Z3 4.1 for Linux: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3-x64-4.1.tar.gz. The following answer explains the name convention : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122735/previous-version-of-z3-for-linux

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura are there plans to eventually release iZ3 with the latest version? Or is that out of MSR's hands given the issue mentioned above about the outside components?