# Is there a 64-bit version of iZ3 for Linux?

Tags: z3

At [How to install iZ3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390388/how-to-install-iz3) there was a link provided to Z3 4.1 for Linux. In this archive, Z3 itself is 64-bit, but iZ3 unfortunately not.

I can not run the 32-bit iZ3 executable on my machine, because it is missing 32-bit shared libraries, which i can not install (they would replace my regular 64-bit libraries).

So, is there a 64-bit version of iZ3 for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the interpolating version of Z3 can only be built from source. Get the branch "interp" source from z3.codeplex.com. The file README contains build instructions, including how to get the external library that is required.