# z3 previous version library

Tags: linux, z3

I am using z3-osx-4.1-x64 running on the max os, currently I need it to run under the linux system. I tried to download the linux version http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/ , but it seems that there is no linux version.
Could you please tell me where I can download it? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the source from [their current site](http://z3.codeplex.com/) and follow the instructions in their [README](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89c1785b7322#README) file.

Comment: btw, I got this by simply following your own link, reading the pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply append `z3-4.1.tar.gz` to http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/ to download Z3 4.1 binaries for Linux.

A more complete list of old versions could be found in [Previous version of Z3 for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122735/previous-version-of-z3-for-linux).

For newest versions, it is recommended to [download the master branch, compile and install on your Linux system](http://z3.codeplex.com/).

Comment: As the link as above, I just can download z3.4.1.msi which seems that run under the window. There no exits any linux versions.

Comment: Have you tried http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3-4.1.tar.gz as per my answer?

Comment: As the link, I download the package z3.4.1, but its library seems to be incompatible, causing the error as below /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible lib/libz3.so when searching for -lz3
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible lib/libz3.a when searching for -lz3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status